# How to get pass error : TypeError: addtrans() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i created a button function 'addtrans" that will create another pop up window and collect some info from user entered into a entry box. That function is a button command. When i click button nothing comes up except the error.

```
def addtrans(self): 
    newWin = Toplevel(root) 
        width = 600
        height = 400 
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height,
                                (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        newWin.geometry(alignstr)
        newWin.resizable(width=False, height=False)   
        self.lbl1 = Label(newWin, text="Enter amount in Euros :", fg='red')
        self.lbl1.place(x=150 , y=50)
        self.euros = Entry(newWin, width=20)
        self.euros.place(x=300, y=50)
        self.lbl2 = Label(newWin, text="CATEGORY :", fg='green') 
        self.lbl2.place(x=150 , y=80)
        self.cat_entry = Entry(newWin, width=20)
        self.cat_entry.place(x=299, y=80)
        self.place_entry = Label(newWin, text=" ENTER NAME OF PLACE :")
        self.place_entry.place(x=140, y=120)
        self.txtfld2 = Entry(newWin, width=20)
        self.txtfld2.place(x=299, y=120)
        self.submit_btn=Button(newWin, text="SUBMIT RECORD TO DATABASE", command=submit)
        self.submit_btn.place(x=280, y=160)
```

Comment: How do you call `addtrans`? Is `addtrans` a method for a class? Did you instanciate the class?

Comment: @TheLizzard it is a method in a class, don't think i instanciate becuz im not sure how

Comment: And how are you calling `addtrans`?

Comment: like this self.addtrans_btn=Button(root, text="ADD TRANSACTION", command=addtrans) @TheLizzard

Comment: Try changing it to `command=self.addtrans`

Comment: when i add that it says : AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'addtrans'

Comment: Are you sure that the `def addtrans(self)` is inside the class definition? Look at your indentation. Also you might want to look at a python object oriented programming tutorial.

Comment: Fix the indentation please. You have probably indented the `addtrans()` inside some function, it should be on same indentation level as `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions your code like this:

```py
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, root, command):
        self.root = root
        self.command = command

    def addtrans(self): 
        root = self.root
        command = self.command
        newWin = Toplevel(root) 
        width = 600
        height = 400 
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height,
                                (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        newWin.geometry(alignstr)
        newWin.resizable(width=False, height=False)   
        self.lbl1 = Label(newWin, text="Enter amount in Euros :", fg='red')
        self.lbl1.place(x=150 , y=50)
        self.euros = Entry(newWin, width=20)
        self.euros.place(x=300, y=50)
        self.lbl2 = Label(newWin, text="CATEGORY :", fg='green') 
        self.lbl2.place(x=150 , y=80)
        self.cat_entry = Entry(newWin, width=20)
        self.cat_entry.place(x=299, y=80)
        self.place_entry = Label(newWin, text=" ENTER NAME OF PLACE :")
        self.place_entry.place(x=140, y=120)
        self.txtfld2 = Entry(newWin, width=20)
        self.txtfld2.place(x=299, y=120)
        self.submit_btn=Button(newWin, text="SUBMIT RECORD TO DATABASE", command=command)
        self.submit_btn.place(x=280, y=160)
```

You could instantiate and call like this:

```py
import tkinter

win = tkinter.Tk()
example = Example(win, lambda: print("submit!"))
example.addtrans()
win.mainloop()
```

If you click "SUBMIT RECORD TO DATABASE" button it will print "submit!"

Comment: Why aren't keeping a reference to the tkinter window? Why aren't you calling `.mainloop()` on it.

Comment: Do you mean `command=command` instead of `command=submit` because `submit` is not defined in your code?

Comment: @TheLizzard It's a bug.I fixed it.